# Groups that can occur as graph automorphisms of a fixed size graph

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, directed-graphs

From theorem $4$ and corollary $1$ in [this book](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cmh/distribution/books0/chapter2.pdf) we have that graph isomorphism has to do with automorphism group of a graph. We also know every group is the automorphism group of a graph by [Frucht's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem). However here I seek something stronger. I want to fix the size of graphs I seek automorphism group.

Given integer $m$ from $1$ to $n$

> 1. how many non-isomorphic subgroups of order $m$ can occur as automorphism group of a graph of size $n$?
> 2. How many distinct subgroups of $S_n$ can occur as automorphism groups of a graph of size $n$?

Is there an easy way to understand 1. and 2. as I am only looking for asymptotics?

> 3. What is the minimum $f(n)$ needed to realize all distinct subgroups of $S_n$ as automorphism group of some graph of size $f(n)$?
> 4. Do any of 1.,2. and 3. change significantly if we are allowed directed graphs?

Comment: for 2., take the complete graph $K_n$. Then every subgroup  of $S_n$ is its automorphism group.

Comment: What do you mean by 'automorphism group'? Do you mean the group of all automorphisms of the graph? If so, only $S_n$ counts as the automorphism group of $K_n$.